# TypeReference created from Generic type does not work as intended

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am trying to parse a JSON string into a `Map<String, Map<Long, Long>>`. I had a method that performed serialization using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` by constructing a `TypeReference` using a generic type, but this did not serialize the object correctly.

The method I was using looked like to serialize the string into Map<String, Map<Long, Long> is this:

```
public static <T> T to(String jsonString) {
    TypeReference<T> typeReference = new TypeReference<T>() {};
    return WrapThrowingSupplier.wrapIOException(() -> new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, typeReference));
}
```

Which I called as follows:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, Long>> map = to(jsonString);
```

However, this did not work, and trying to iterate through the inner map's keyset like:

```
innerMap.forEach(entry -> //do things with long key);
```

threw `ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long`.

I'm guessing that the `String` keys in the JSON could not be converted to `Long` in the inner map.
However, I tried doing this after looking at another SO answer:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, Long>> map2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

which works as expected. What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `to` method doesn’t know what `T` is and the `TypeReference` class has no way to create information that doesn’t exist. All it carries to the JSON deserializer, is “`T`”.

In contrast, your statement

```java
Map<String, Map<Long, Long>> map2 = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

*does* know that the intended target type is `Map<String, Map<Long, Long>>` and the compiler infers that you are creating a `new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<Long, Long>>>() {}` (this works since Java 9).

In other words, the purpose of the `TypeReference` is to carry the type information from a code location where the actual type is known through the generic methods. It does not work when you create the `TypeReference` in a generic method where the type information is already lost.